# Finding equal partial sum given two $N$-tuples of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

This is an interesting question which I haven't found anyone addressing it.

> Let $N$ be a fixed natural number, $(a_1, \cdots, a_N), (b_1, \cdots, b_N)$ two $N$-tuples of natural numbers with $a_i, b_j \in \{1, 2. \cdots, N\}$. Does there exist a subcollection $(a_{i_1}, \cdots, a_{i_k})$, $(b_{j_1}, \cdots, b_{j_l})$ so that 
>   $$a_{i_1} + \cdots + a_{i_k} = b_{j_1} + \cdots + b_{j_l}?$$

Example : say $N=3$. Consider $(1,1,2)$ and $(1,3,3)$. Obviously there are equal partial sums.  Take $1, 2$ from the first triples and $3$ from the second, we got $1+2 =3$.

Or , you can find another equal sum: Take $1 =1$ for example.

For example for $N=4$. Similarly we can always find an equal sum. Let's check this with a few trials. Say we have
$$(4, 4,4,4), (3,3,3,2).$$
We can find at least one equal sum as follows: $4+4 =3+3+2$.

Another trial : $(1,1,1,1)$, $(2,3,2,3)$. We can find easily even more than one equal sum: $1+1=2$, $1+1+1 =3$ etc...

I always found equal partial sums. I couldn't find a counter example. I am asking either for a counter example or a proof.

**Remark**: 
I know that the statement is true for two $2N$-tuples with numbers ranged from $1$ to $N$. In this case the proof is easy with the pigeonhole principle. You must get two subgroups which are equal. Moreover you would get sequences which are equal.

But would that hold true for sets of length $N$? The simple proof that works for $2N$ wouldn't hold here. On the other hand I couldn't find any counter example for $N$.

Is it true or not?  Is it possible to prove one way or the other?

Comment: This is not clear.  There is only one set of $N$ numbers from $\{1,\cdots, N\}$.  Maybe a numerical example with small $N$ will help clarify.

Comment: No.  I mean, the numbers could range from 1 to N.   Repetition allowed too.

Comment: I edited to clarify it

Comment: Still more clarification feels necessary. What are partial sums and how many of them should be equal? Do you mean there must be at least two non-empty subsets, one on each side, such that their sums are equal?

Comment: By 'must possess ' obviously I mean at least one. Which is the requirement.  Yes , it's exactly the way you described it.

Comment: But must the set possess "all" partial sums equal, or "at least one" partial sum equal? Also, the phrase "partial sum" could be interpreted many ways, especially considering the fact that you are describing multisets (lists?) and not sets: sets may not contain duplicate elements.

Comment: Given two series of numbers of size N.   Numbers inside can be duplicate as much as you want.  The claim is: you will always be able to take a few objects from one series and a few from the second that their sums are equal.   I showed an example in the question.   Not all partial sums are equal.   You must find at least one

Comment: Hi, I have (quite extensively) edit your question, Please check if it is still what you want to ask. Using $N$-tuples seems to be clearer than multisets IMO. In any case you can just rollback the edit.

Comment: OK.   Thanx.   Not familiar with the name tuples as English isn't my mother tongue.   But I believe you know what you are saying.

Comment: The example is not clear, whether $i_n$ is $(1,1,2)$ or $a_n$ is $(1,1,2)$.

Comment: Also what sequence is $i_n, j_n$?

Comment: @Takahiro: The question is quite simple. Given 2 collections of N natural numbers in the interval [1..N], is it always true that the sum of 1 or more numbers in one collection is equal to the sum of 1 or more numbers in the other collection?

Comment: Takahiro@ a is the collection of (1,1,2) and (1,2) forms the partial sum 1+2=3 what you may call the i  collection.

Comment: Even if odd number $2N-1$, it would be similar proof to 2N's version by pigeonhole principle. IMO, just change a bit.

Comment: The question is about N

Comment: Can you add or reference the easy proof by pigeonhole principle for $2N$-tuples to the question?

Comment: Ok, for the record... I think the easy pigeonhole proof for $2N$-tuples is the same as my answer without "choice (3)", where you add an element from $a$ and an element from $b$ simultaneously.  In that case ... adding one element at a time ... you get to take $2N$ steps and keep the sums between about $-N$ and $N$, but it seems tricky to control the partial sums any further.

Comment: I've amplified the statement. Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795585/contiguous-subsequences-with-equal-sums).

Answer (score 12):

Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ be sequences drawn from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Assume w.n.l.g. that $a_1 \ge b_1$.  Starting with $a'=b'=()$, and keeping track of $S=\sum a' - \sum b'$, repeat the following step (*) $n+1$ times: (1) append the next element of $a$ to $a'$, or (2) append the next element of $b$ to $b'$, or (3) do both; you must choose (1) on the first step and (2) on the second, and your choices must keep $S\in[0,n]$.  Since $S$ has now assumed $n+2$ values (counting its initial value of $0$), by the pigeonhole principle it must have assumed the same value twice, say before step $k$ and after step $l\ge k$.  Then the elements appended to $a'$ and $b'$ on steps $k$ through $l$ must have equal sums.

This proves that $a$ and $b$ have not only subsets, but contiguous *subsequences*, with equal sums.

(*) Of course, the proof rests on showing that you *can* successfully repeat this step -- i.e., that one of the three choices satisfies the constraint on $S$ -- the required number of times.  Suppose $a$ and $b$ have elements remaining, and $a_i$ and $b_j$ are their next elements.  Choice (1) succeeds unless $S+a_i > n$, and choice (2) succeeds unless $S-b_j < 0$.  If both fail, then, choice (3) must succeed, because we have $0 \le n-b_j < S+a_i-b_j <a_i\le n$.  So we can repeat the step until either $a$ or $b$ is exhausted: at least $n-1$ additional times after the first two steps, which were forced to choose (1) and (2) respectively, for a total of at least $n+1$ times.

Comment: This is a beautiful combination of dynamic programming and the pigeonhole principle. Well done!