# Contiguous subsequences with equal sums

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

This is a stronger version of statement from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776479/finding-equal-partial-sum-given-two-n-tuples-of-natural-numbers) question.

> Let $n \ge 2$ be an integer. Suppose we have two tuples $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k), (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m)$ of positive integers not larger than $n$. It is also known that:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle \sum_{i\,=\,1}^k x_i > \sum_{i\,=\,1}^m y_i$;
> 2. $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) \ne (n, n, \dots, n)$;
> 3. $m \ge n-1$.
>
> Then there exist $p,q,r,s$ such that $1 \le p \le q \le k,\, 1 \le r \le s \le m$ and
> $$\sum_{i\,=\,p}^q x_i = \sum_{i\,=\,r}^s y_i.$$

Can you prove it?

**Avowal.** I know the proof. So let me omit usual 'justification' clause. Consider this a challenge question. I can give hints instead (only if it turns out to be hard).